# How to write a spec for a website

Tags: specifications

As I'm starting to develop for the web, I'm noticing that having a document between the client and myself that clearly lays out what they want would be very helpful for both parties. After reading some of Joel's advice, doing anything without a spec is a headache, unless of course your billing hourly ;)

1. In those that have had experience,
   what is a good way to extract all
   the information possible from the
   client about what they want their
   website to do and how it looks? Good
   ways to avoid feature creep?
2. What web specific requirements
   should I be aware of? (graphic
   design perhaps)
3. What do you use to write your specs in?
4. Any thing else one should know?

Thanks!

Ps: to "StackOverflow Purists" , if my question sucks, i'm open to feed back on how to improve it rather than votes down and "your question sucks" comments

Comment: good Post script: I up for the same.Its good to be direct than missing on something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on the goal of the web-site. If it is a site to market a new product being released by the client, it is easier to narrow down the spec, if it's a general site, then it's a lot of back and forth.

Outline the following:

- What is the goal of the site / re-design.
- What is the expected raise in customer base?
- What is the customer retainment goal?
- What is the target demographic?
- Outline from the start all the interactive elements - flash / movies / games.
- Outline the IA, sit down with the client and outline all the sections they want. Think up of how to organize it and bring it back to them.
- Get all changes in writing.
- Do all spec preparation before starting development to avoid last minute changes.

Some general pointers

- Be polite, but don't be too easy-going. If the client is asking for something impossible, let them know that in a polite way. Don't say YOU can't do it, say it is not possible to accomplish that in the allotted time and budget.
- Avoid making comparisons between your ideas and big name company websites. Don't say your search function will be like Google, because you set a certain kind of standard for your program that the user is used to.
- Follow standards in whatever area of work you are. This will make sure that the code is not only easy to maintain later but also avoid the chances of bugs.
- Stress accessibility to yourself and the client, it is a **big** a thing.

More stuff:

- Do not be afraid to voice your opinion. Of course, the client has the money and the decision at hand whether to work with you - so be polite. But don't be a push-over, you have been in the industry and you know how it works, so let them know what will work and what won't.
- If the client stumbles on your technical explanations, don't assume they are stupid, they are just in another industry.
- Steer the client away from cliches and buzz words. Avoid throwing words like 'ajax' and 'web 2.0' around, unless you have the exact functionality in mind.
- Make sure to plan everything before you start work as I have said above. If the site is interactive, you have to make sure everything meshes together. When the site is thought up piece by piece, trust me it is noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

One piece of advice that I've seen in many software design situations (not just web site design) relates to user expectations.  Some people manage them well by giving the user something to see, while making sure that the user doesn't believe that the thing they're seeing can actually work.

Paper prototyping can help a lot for this type of situation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_prototyping

Comment: I thought that was more of a joke, but the article says it actually looks like a effective method

Answer (score 0):

I'm with the paper prototyping, but use iplotz.com for it, which is working out fine so far from us.
It makes you think about how the application should work in more detail, and thus makes it less likely to miss out on certain things you need to build, and it makes it much easier to explain to the client what you are thinking of.
You can also ask the client to use iplotz to explain the demands to you, or cooperate in it.

Answer (score 0):

I also found looking for client questionnaires on google a good idea to help generate some more ideas:

Google: [web client questionnaire](http://www.google.com/search?q=web+client+questionnaire&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&hs=Dgl&start=10&sa=N),
There are dozens of pdfs and other forms to learn from